# Problem: Inconsistencies in the existing project dependencies found. Version incompatibility between: - com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0@aar

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, bottomnavigationview

I want to add bottom navigation view to my app but when i add the dependency it shows the following error and it crashes on runtime.[here is the screenshot of error it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcigU.png)

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.3.2-appcompat'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0'
}                                                                       
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Post your dependency list file here.